# Какой функцией можно получить указатель на устройство из PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR по dbcc_name

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Как вариант я могу перечислять все устройства получать их DEVICE_ID и сравнивать со своим dbcc_name(но это какие-то грабли). Возможно существует функция которая сразу вернёт указатель на устройство приняв входным параметром dbcc_name??? Чтобы получить например DEVINST именно этого устройства.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uiMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL == wParam || DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE == wParam)
    {
        PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR lpdb = (PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR)lParam;

        if (lpdb->dbch_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE)
        {
            PDEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE lpdbd = (PDEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE)lpdb;
            lpdbd->dbcc_name;// \\?\USB#Vid_04e8&Pid_503b# 0002F9A9828E0F06#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}
        }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uiMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Windows нет понятия "указатель на устройство". Возможно, вы имели в виду "дескриптор"?

Насчет получения DEVINST, для этого необходимо сначала получить Device Instance ID с помощью функции [CM_Get_Device_Interface_Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/cfgmgr32/nf-cfgmgr32-cm_get_device_interface_propertyw). После этого, полученный Device Instance ID нужно передать в CM_Locate_DevNode, которая вернет значение DEVINST.

```
#include <windows.h>
#define INITGUID
#include "Devpkey.h"
#include "dbt.h"
#include "cfgmgr32.h"

#pragma comment( lib, "Cfgmgr32.lib" )

//<...>

if (lpdb->dbch_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE)
{
    PDEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE lpdbd = (PDEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE)lpdb;
    DEVPROPTYPE type = 0;
    WCHAR buffer[1024]={0};
    ULONG size = sizeof(buffer);
    DEVINST devinst;
    CONFIGRET result;

    //получение Device Instance ID
    result = CM_Get_Device_Interface_Property(lpdbd->dbcc_name, &DEVPKEY_Device_InstanceId, &type, (BYTE*)buffer, &size, 0);

    if(result  != CR_SUCCESS){
        MessageBox(hWnd,L"CM_Get_Device_Interface_Property failed",NULL,MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }  

    //получение DEVINST    
    result = CM_Locate_DevNode(&devinst, buffer, CM_LOCATE_DEVNODE_NORMAL);

    if(result  != CR_SUCCESS){
        MessageBox(hWnd,L"CM_Locate_DevNode failed",NULL,MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Источник: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5ec29644-d676-406b-9b16-4471cc7ef19b/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-devinst-or-device-instance-id-from-the-device-name-or-viceversa?forum=wdk